# reversing the order of all elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have tried using

CSS:

```
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

and

Javascript:

```
var reversed = document.getElementsByTagName('span').reverse();
document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerHTML = reversed;
```

to reverse the order of the span inside the div while keeping them inline but does not work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="row">
  <span class="col-3">1</span>
  <span class="col-3">2</span>
  <span class="col-3">3</span>
  <span class="col-3">4</span>
  <span class="col-3">5</span>
  <span class="col-3">6</span>
  <span class="col-3">7</span>
  <span class="col-3">8</span>
  <span class="col-3">9</span>
  <span class="col-3">10</span>
</div>
```

intended result is

```
10    9    8    7
6     5    4    3
2     1
```

Comment: This is effectively a different question to what everyone below has answered below - so you have multiple answers based on your original question that make no sense. Please ensure your question is accurate and exactly what you intend to ask before you submit.

Comment: It's not so useful to change your question to work without flex all of a sudden. People have already answered your question. Making it look like bootstrap or using the grid system in their answers is out of scope of your question.

Comment: Asked and answered, question should be reverted to https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55361689/1

Comment: when asked the question thought the functionality would not be changed but then i found the difference so had to fix it with the actual code css sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` and `justify-content: flex-end`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

> With JS

```js
function change(){
  let spans = document.querySelectorAll('.row > span')
  let div = document.querySelector('.row');
  ([...spans]).reverse().forEach(e=>{
    div.appendChild(e)
  })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button onClick='change()'>Reverse</button>
<div class="row">
  <span class="col-3">1</span>
  <span class="col-3">2</span>
  <span class="col-3">3</span>
  <span class="col-3">4</span>
  <span class="col-3">5</span>
  <span class="col-3">6</span>
  <span class="col-3">7</span>
  <span class="col-3">8</span>
  <span class="col-3">9</span>
  <span class="col-3">10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @JoeDoe added a method with JS too

Comment: is there a method for mass implementation using javascript instead of appending one by one for spans more than 1000 span for speed?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps:

- Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all `<span>` elements
- Use Spread Operator to convert the result of `querySelectorAll` to `Array`
- Use `Array.prototype.reverse()` on that
- Use `querySelector()` to get `<div>` and use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let spans =  [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].reverse().forEach(elm => {
  div.appendChild(elm);
})
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` here, along with `justify-content` to align the items to the left instead of right which will happen when you use the `row-reverse` as the value.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Also, am not sure if you are looking for a JS solution, but I don't think you need that as you can achieve the above with flex only.

Answer (score 0):

With `column-reverse`, you're effectively turning them into block elements so whilst it will alter the order, it will also put the `span` elements one under the other.

I would suggest trying `row-reverse` instead - this will keep them all inline whilst giving you the order you want. Then to ensure it remains on the left side of the page, use `justify-content:flex-end;` like below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```