# reversing anchors and inserting them using innerHTML give me text

Tags: javascript

```js
function rvs(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var anchors = [...anchors].reverse();
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = anchors;
  
}
```

```html
<div id='x' onclick="rvs()">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
</div>
```

i want to insert the reversed value **all at once** using `innerHTML` beause i have more than **1000 anchor** and it takes too long to **iterate it one by one** into the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> i used for of before with appendChild but it ate the entire memory for 10s and froze the browser to reverse my 1000 elements. that why want to insert them all at once

To reappend them all at once, you'd use a document fragment:

```
function rvs(){
  // Using qSA to get a disconnected NodeList
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (const anchor of anchors) {
    fragment.insertBefore(anchor, fragment.firstChild);
  }
  target.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

```js
var target = document.getElementById('x');
function createElements() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = `#${i}`;
    a.textContent = `[${i}]`;
    target.appendChild(a);
  }
}
function rvs(){
  // Using qSA to get a disconnected NodeList
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (const anchor of anchors) {
    fragment.insertBefore(anchor, fragment.firstChild);
  }
  target.appendChild(fragment);
}
createElements();
setTimeout(() => {
  console.time("reverse");
  rvs();
  console.timeEnd("reverse");
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id='x'>
</div>
```

Or if you want to make a round-trip through HTML (but that will remove any event handlers on these elements), you need to use `outerHTML` on the anchors:

```
function rvs(){
  const html = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    anchor => anchor.outerHTML
  );
  target.innerHTML = html.reverse().join("");
}
```

```js
var target = document.getElementById('x');
function createElements() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = `#${i}`;
    a.textContent = `[${i}]`;
    target.appendChild(a);
  }
}
function rvs(){
  const html = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    anchor => anchor.outerHTML
  );
  target.innerHTML = html.reverse().join("");
}
createElements();
setTimeout(() => {
  console.time("reverse");
  rvs();
  console.timeEnd("reverse");
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id='x'>
</div>
```

---

A word of warning: Your original code assumes that the `HTMLCollection` you get back from `getElementsByTagName` is iterable. The specification does **not** require it to be iterable, and while it is iterable on some browsers, it isn't on others. (In contrast, the `NodeList` you get from `querySelectorAll` **is** iterable per spec, although not all browsers implement that yet.)

You can polyfill iterability on both of them like this, in environments that have ES2015+ support:

```
function applyIterable(target) {
    if (target.prototype && !target.prototype.forEach) {
        // Yes, there's really no need for `Object.defineProperty` here
        target.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !target.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {
            Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
                value: Array.prototype[Symbol.itereator],
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined") {
    applyIterable(NodeList);
}
if (typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined") {
    applyIterable(HTMLCollection);
}
```

In environments that don't have ES2015+ support, that will still polyfill `forEach` for you.

Comment: i used `for of` before with `appendChild` but it ate the entire memory for 10s and froze the browser to reverse my 1000 elements. that why  want to insert them all at once

Comment: @JoeDoe - In that case, you'll need to move them into a document fragment and then append the fragment. Or if you want to make a roundtrip through markup, use `outerHTML` on each of the anchors to get its markup (trashes event handlers, though).

Comment: @JoeDoe - Be interesting to know how the second solution above (using `insertBefore`) compares in your 1000-element scenario (probably not much better, though).

Comment: @JoeDoe - Added an example doing 1000 elements with a document fragment. Takes about 3ms in this example in Chrome v73 on my workstation.

Comment: can not i just get the reversed array of elements then convert it into a string then use innerHTML for it or it would be worst?

Comment: @JoeDoe - I've also added an example making the round-trip through markup via `outerHTML` on each anchor. It's about 3.7ms in my setup. You could use `innerHTML` on the target to get the markup of all the elements at once, but then you have to split it up and reverse the order. I suspect that would take longer. Good luck with it.

Comment: **document fragment** is a lot faster and efficent yes also can the `Array.prototype.map.call` be translated into a loop because i do not undertand how it works

Comment: It's basically `const html = []; for (const anchor of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) { html.push(anchor.outerHTML); }` It applies the `map` function of arrays, but to the `HTMLCollection` you get from `getElementsByTagName` (because `map` is intentionally generic, it doesn't require that `this` within `map` be an actual array). Separately, I've added a word of warning at the end of the answer about something you were relying on in yoru code that isn't reliable. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS approach. This is not supposed to be the answer but I thought I should post it. You can use a flex box!

```css
#x{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'>
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If this can be used on the structer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361689 then that would be great

Comment: @JoeDoe You already have an accepted answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361793/9920079) using flexbox for that question. So I am kind of confused as to what you want? Do you want the `<a>` elements to be like the intended result of the `<span>` elements in that question?

Comment: yes if it can be done using css then there would be no need for javascript answers in the question

Comment: @ajaiJothi Thank you. But the OP wishes for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to @Hackinet answer, I came up with CSS only solution, but the problem here is if the anchor has href, it doesn't work, in that case we can write a simple js method to toggle the `flex-direction` property between `row` and `row-reverse`

```css
label{
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

#reverse {
  display:none;
}

#reverse:checked+label{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="reverse">
<label for="reverse">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
</label>
```